# Memory use during recursion in Python

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, recursion

I've implemented a recursive function which takes as parameter a numpy array.
Here the simplified version:

```
 def rec(arr):

     rec(arr[indices])
```

In every recursive call I use a part of the array indexed by some indices.

My question is about the memory load: how does python handle this? Does it makes a copy of the array at each call or not?

Comment: I do not see any relation between recursion and what your question is about. If you use a loops instead you think the memory usage would be different?

Comment: @Bakuriu: I guess the relevance of recursion is that a 15-level-deep recursion implies there are 15 segments of `arr` that are alive at the same time. With iteration, this may or may not be the case. But I agree that this question appears to be entirely about the memory use of `arr[indices]` and not about recursion per se.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the nature of `indices`. If it's a slice, there is no copy. If, on the other hand, you're using [fancy indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-0dffc419afa7d77d51062d40d2d84143db8216c2), then a copy is made.

I recommend reading [Copies and Views](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-1529ae93dd5d431ffe3a1001a4ab1a394e70a5f2) in the NumPy tutorial (even though the section does not cover fancy indexing).

Comment: Indices is an array of indices which index a slice of arr. So it does not make a copy right?

Comment: @JohnEntropy: If the elements of `indices` are integers, that's fancy indexing, so a copy *is* made.